# Is there a way to get all available elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get all html tag names supported by the browser for an web application I am building. I mean something like this:

```
console.log(getAllElements())
//[a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, area, base, ...]
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? All of the element names? Text nodes also?

Comment: I mean all html tag names that are available in the browser

Comment: With web components anyone can create their own HTML elements so in current versions of Firefox, Chrome and Opera the concept of "available elements" does not have a definite answer because you can make your own element

Comment: *A long time ago, in a web standard far, far away...*  one could access all the entities declared in the DTD through [`document.doctype.entities`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1788794630). But it's been removed from the specs and browsers a long time ago (and HTML5 doesn't even have a DTD referencing all the entities anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible really. Let me tell you why:

First I expected that all of the possible elements will be represented by and interface on the `window` object, like `window.HTMLDivElement`. This is true for many, and you can see the result by executing this (putting svg aside for the sake of the argument):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(name => /HTML.*Element/.test(name))`

There are **2 problems** with the resulting array. First, the names, even if you extract the name and leave out the `HTML` and `Element` part, differ from the tag names. Example: `HTMLDListElement` vs `<datalist>`. So naturally, one tries to instantiate that element to see how it is represented in the markup, like `new HTMLDivElement()`, but that is a prohibited operation!

Second problem is, that not all elements are represented by their own interface. Some are generic enough, like `<section>`, that they are represented by the generic `HTMLElement`, which doesn't give you any information useful for your case.

**Another approach**, is to use `document.createElement` to check if an arbitrary element is really native, judging by its properties. Now that works for elements like `<video>`, which have special properties, making them distinguishable from custom elements, but again, not every element is like that, and using `<section>` as an example again, properties-wise, it is virtually indistinguishable from creating a custom element like `<sssection>`.

So no, there is no way to find out really other than checking browser's adherence to spec and listing the elements manually.

Comment: "it is virtually indistinguishable from creating a custom element like <sssection>." No true: `document.createElement("section") instanceof HTMLUnknownElement` -> `false`. `document.createElement("ssection") instanceof HTMLUnknownElement` -> `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without using third party tools and matching against some version number of the browser this is not possible with the current DOM api.

In general you should not care and **fall back** to ensure accessibility of your document.

HTML is a backwards compatible standard and the browser just ignores unknown tags
rendering the text inside instead. That's why it's still good practice to put these
kind of fallbacks

```html
<video controls width="250">

    <source src="/some/video.webm"
            type="video/webm">

    <source src="/some/video.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

What you might want is instead to check for specific DOM api that **you app needs** (service workers, audio processing...) and implement something
equivalent in JS to provide older browsers support.